# create function must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error from the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getLavel(@id int ,@lavel char)
RETURNS date
BEGIN
 DECLARE @date date
    select @date = (select authorization_date from Authorized WHERE diver_number = @id and @lavel =level_name)
    return @date
END
GO
```

What can be the reason?

Ty very much.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Because you jammed everything onto a single line. Why are you using a subquery to populate a variable? This whole thing looks like a good candidate for an intvf instead of a scalar function.

Comment: Is your statement included with others in a script?  If so, the statement before your function needs a `GO` at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turn this into an inline table valued function. This will perform better than the scalar function. Also, you should NOT use the default sizes for character datatypes. Do you know what the default length for a char is? Did you know that it can vary based on usage?

```
CREATE FUNCTION getLavel
(
    @id int
    , @lavel char --You need to define the length instead of the default length
) 
RETURNS table
return 
    select authorization_date 
    from Authorized 
    WHERE diver_number = @id 
        and @lavel = level_name

GO
```

Comment: that's worked!
how do i call this function and send the variables?

    ALTER TABLE Diving ADD CONSTRAINT...

Comment: i tried:

    'ALTER TABLE Diving
    ADD CONSTRAINT getLavel CHECK (dbo.getLavel(guide,"guide") != null );'

but i get this error:
    Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.getLavel", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: You are creating the scalar so you can use it as a constraint on your column? You did not mention that initially. You can't use a table valued function as a constraint hack. You will have to go back to a scalar function for that.

Comment: I'm sorry,
Can you explain what is the different in scalar function?

Comment: Try this link. It can explain it more clearly than I can. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 36):

The function needs to be either the only function in the query window OR the only statement in the batch. If there are more statements in the query window, you can make it the only one "in the batch" by surrounding it with GO's.

e.g.

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION getLavel(@id int ,@lavel char)
RETURNS date
BEGIN
 DECLARE @date date
    select @date = (select authorization_date from Authorized WHERE     diver_number = @id and @lavel =level_name)
    return @date
END
GO
```

Comment: Note: This "GO" separator is depend on the client application. `GO` is the default for SSMS for example, but it can be changed to anything else that you want. It is important to remember that this is not related to the server. It simply "tell" the client to send the code between these two `GO` as one batch

Answer (score 4):

You need to add RETURN before the END statement

That should fix your issue, that's what fixed mine. :D

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that this statement is the only the only sql in your query window before you execute it.

Or you can highlight the function declaration and execute

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me, was that I was trying to create the function inside of a transaction context - that doesn't make sense from a SQL Server point of view.  Transactions are for data, not functions.

Take the CREATE FUNCTION statement out of the transaction, then wrap it in GO's

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CalculateAge(@DOB  DATE) 
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Age INT
SET @DOB='08/12/1990'
SET @Age =DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()) -
   CASE
        WHEN (MONTH (@DOB)>  MONTH (GETDATE ())) OR
             (MONTH (@DOB)= MONTH (GETDATE ())  AND DAY (@DOB) >DAY (GETDATE ()))

    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
    END 
SELECT @Age
END
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would help if you add some explanation about why this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Error is given to you in only query Page But if you execute the query then it will successfully execute.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getLavel(@id int ,@lavel char)
RETURNS date
BEGIN
 DECLARE @date date
    select @date = (select authorization_date from Authorized WHERE diver_number = @id and @lavel = level_name)
    return @date
END
GO
```